# Compress image in android (b4a)

Tags: android, basic4android

I'm using this java code to compress an image in **basic4android**! However, nothing works!

```
#if java
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import java.io.*;
import android.os.Environment;
public void Resize(Bitmap mPhoto)
{
    try
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        mPhoto.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bytes);

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+"11111.jpg");
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
}
#end if
```

No file is shown under ExternalStorageDirectory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try first to create a directory in the root directory and then write the file in it like this for example:

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath() + “/your-dir-name/”);
dir.mkdir();
File file = new File(dir, “11111.jpg”);
FileOutputStream os = outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
os.write(bytes.toByteArray());
os.close();
```

And please do not forget to add this permission to your AndroidManifest-file

```
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE” />
```

Comment: thank you my friend.image was created ! but the new problem is after compressing instead of lower size image size increased !!! a jpeg image with 970 KB is now 2 MB !!! what should i do ???!!!

Comment: i found solution , i should use : Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG . tnx.

Comment: Great that you found a working solution for you! You're welcome :)